# C# XAML serialization of content fields

Tags: c#, xaml, serialization

I have a basic text drawing class that contains the "Text" as a "content" property as well as it needs to be serialized as an ATTRIBUTE, but rather it returns as a normal text element like Sample

```
[ContentProperty("Text")]
public class TextElement
{ [XmlAttribute("Text")]
    public string Text
    {
        get { return textBase.Text;  }
        set { textBase.Text = value; }

    }
```

I have used XamlServices & XamlWriter but the results is the same, Any solutions ?

Comment: do you have a base class for your TextElement?

Answer (score 0):

Try decorating the Text property with the DesignerSerializationOptionsAttribute:

[DesignerSerializationOptions(DesignerSerializationOptions.SerializeAsAttribute)]

See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.designerserializationoptionsattribute.aspx

The XmlAttributeAttribute only affects XmlSerializer serialization.